# Filtering message form the redis queue PyRSMQ

Tags: python, redis, queue

I am using PyRSMQ to send and receive messages. Let say I have a Queue name "test" and I am pushing a message as "*_batch1" and "*_batch2" from the sender and in the consumer I need to subscribe to the "test" queue and read only the message that has patten as "*_batch1". How I can do using Redis to filter messages in a Queue or is there is any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use worker class to process the messages. If the worker processing function return True the message will be deleted from the queue if not it remains in the queue for other workers to pick up.

for example:

```
def process(message_id, message, rc, ts):
    # process message here
    m_json = json.loads(message)
    if m_message["job1"]:
        # do something with message if job1
        # if return True the message will be deleted from queue
        return True
    else:
        # if return false message will be visible again in queue and wont be delted
        return False

# create worker for the queue and run it somewhere in your code, like in main()
rsqm_consumer = RedisSMQConsumer(qname=args.queue,
                                 processor=process,
                                 host=args.host, port=args.port, ns=args.ns, vt=args.vt,
                                 empty_queue_delay=args.empty_queue_delay, trace=args.trace)
```